# Code bbcode in phpbb3

Tags: bbcode, phpbb3

Here is a question for the code bbcode in phpbb3. As we can see [here](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2122696) (official site of phpbb3) two ways of presenting a code are used. Is this a bbcode? If so, how can I add it to the board? If not, is this a mod? If yes, where can I find it?

I have searched a lot of how I can achieve a result like this but I came up empty. I appreciate for your help.

**Edit:** I am talking of course about the code that is presented as an inline next to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how phpBB implement it, but you could use BBcode to achieve the same effect. To add custom BBcode go to the `Posting` tab in your ACP, and `BBcodes` is the first option in the left column.

BBcode usage:

```
[inline-code]{TEXT}[/inline-code]
```

HTML replacement:

```
<span style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;border: 1px solid #c9d2d8;color: #2e8b57;display: inline;font-family: Monaco,"Andale Mono","Courier New",Courier,monospace;font-size: 0.9em;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.3em;padding: 0 3px;">{TEXT}</span>
```

Help line:

```
[inline-code]Your code here[/inline-code]
```

The above css is taken from the link you posted so should look the same on your site.

Comment: Thank you.. That worked. Well PhpBB is full of surprises !! But the code you gave works perfect.